# Как работает Intent?

Tags: java, android-intent

Обьясните пожалуйста каждую строчку что она делает.

Задолбался уже с этим Intent, ничерта не могу понять как он работает.

Вернее теоретически понимаю что intent вызывает другую активность внутри приложения или в других приложениях явным или неявным образом.

Но как, не понимаю.

```
private void callSendMeMail() { 
    Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND); 
    Email.setType("text/email"); 
    Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mail@mail.com" }); 
    Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ATM_Support"); 
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Отправить сообщение разработчику")); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Система `Android` - это посредник. `Intent` предназначен для организации взаимодействия между компонентами `Android` с помощью `Android`. Вы не отправляете сообщение какому-либо приложению напрямую, вы отправляете Системе. Система пробегает по Манифестам всех установленных приложений и ищет те приложения, что объявили способность выполнить действие, которое вы передаете аргументом в `Intent`, то есть `Intent.ACTION_SEND` - отправку сообщения.

Далее вы задаете тип данных в этом сообщении - `text/email`. Через `.putExtra` вы вносите дополнительную информацию, а именно сообщаете по какому адресу необходимо отправить сообщение (`Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL`) и тему сообщения (`Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT`).

`startActivity` запускает механизм отправки. `Intent.createChooser` получая собранный вами `Intent` предложит выбрать Пользователю Приложение по умолчанию (если их несколько) для отправки сообщения.

Comment: Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста зачем писать new String[]{"mail@mail.com" } в этой строке : 
Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mail@mail.com" }); ? 

Могу ли я указать после : Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, переменную которая будет хранить в себе имейл ?

Comment: @ФлешРоман: putExtra(...) - перегруженный метод. Вот ваш [вариант](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[])). [Вот то](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#putExtra(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)), что вам, возможно, нужно.

Answer (score 1):

Сначала декларируем, что мы собираемся что-то послать (*Intent* переводится как намерение)

```
Intent Email = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
```

Далее, говорим, что *mime* тип того, что мы собираемся послать будет такой то

```
Email.setType("text/email");
```

Дополнительно сообщаем еще параметры `Intent`'а

```
Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"mail@mail.com" }); 
Email.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "ATM_Support");
```

Далее сообщаем ОСи что у нас есть такое то намерение, при этом дополнительно просим (`createChooser()`), что если обработчиков намерения несколько - то предложить выбор.

```
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(Email, "Отправить сообщение разработчику"))
```

В итоге если в системе есть несколько программ, которые посылают email, то будет предложен выбор, если ни одного, то выскочит предупреждалка типа:

> сорян нет таких

ОСь определяет какую `Activity`/приложение запускать ориентируясь на тип и экшн `Intent`'а